# How to reference SQL columns containing quotes?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, string, alias

I am having trouble referencing the "current" column. It was originally named using quotes, and I am not sure how to reference it.
I have tried:

```
 colName = "\"current\"";
 colName = "\'current\'";
 colName = "current";

 Using the query:
 query = "SELECT" + colName "FROM myTable";
 cmd = new SQLCommand(query,Conn);
 cmd.CommandText = query;
 adpt = new SQLDataAdapter(query,Conn);
 table = new DataTable();
 adpt.Fill(table);
```

All to no avail. It keeps saying the column does not belong to the table, I can easily reference any other column successfully.

```
 CREATE TABLE dbo.myTable
(
   id              int identity    NOT NULL,
   puffid          int,
   summaryid       int,
   serial_number   int,
   puff_date_time  datetime,
   x_angle         numeric(8,3)    DEFAULT ((0)),
   y_angle         numeric(8,3)    DEFAULT ((0)),
   z_angle         numeric(8,3)    DEFAULT ((0)),
   voltage         numeric(8,3)    DEFAULT ((0)),
   "current"       numeric(8,3)    DEFAULT ((0)));
   GRANT DELETE, REFERENCES, UPDATE, SELECT, INSERT ON dbo.myTable TO dbo;
```

I really have no idea how to reference this thing. I can't change the column name or it will break multiple other parts of the project.

Comment: What is your `quoted_identifier` setting? In SQL Server use `[current]`

Comment: You mean `["current"]` @Stu ;)

Comment: Oh - if the column name actually *contains* the quotes? Lol

Comment: Try `query = "SELECT [\"current\"] FROM myTable";`

Comment: Using non-alphanumeric characters in an identifier is a really bad idea. @ThomA has the right answer. In any case, this is just asking for trouble. These bad names will haunt your for years to come.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to wrap them into `[` and `]` and you need spaces around them as well:

```
 colName = "\"current\"";

 Using the query:
 query = "SELECT [" + colName + "] FROM myTable";
 cmd = new SQLCommand(query,Conn);
 cmd.CommandText = query;
 adpt = new SQLDataAdapter(query,Conn);
 table = new DataTable();
 adpt.Fill(table);
```

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, if you can, I suggest you rename the column to `current`. This can be done with `sp_rename`:

```sql
EXEC sys.sp_rename N'dbo.myTable.["current"]',N'current','COLUMN';
```

If you can't, then you'll need to escape the double quotes that are part of the name or use T-SQL's delimit identifier too. Either `"""current"""` or `["current"]` would work to reference the column.

Comment: Keep in mind that `"""current"""` will only work with `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` on, which was clearly not the case when the table was created.

Comment: If people are setting `QUOTED_IDENTITIER` to off in 2023, then I have concerns for their sanity, @madreflection . ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I am joining a project about 3 years in, renaming columns seems a bit risky. using    colName = "\"current\""          SELECT  [colName] FROM myTable is the correct answer. Many Thanks!

Comment: Hey, no argument here, @ThomA! But it's worth mentioning because the `CREATE TABLE` in the question would not have created it with the quotes in the name if `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` had been on.

Comment: Also, while renaming the column will break existing code, you can create views and functions on top that alias the table column, to work towards migrating future code towards sanity...